# adding onclick event to html select option

Tags: javascript, onclick, html-select

I added **onclick** event to my select tag like in the following code -

```
<option onclick="alert('Hello')">Say Hello</option>
```

but it does not work....

How can I set the **option** **onclick** event to fire ?

Comment: we don't have click event for `option`. use `onchange` event in `select` instead.

Comment: I couldn't comment because i don't have 50 reps. In my case i need onclick event for the option element because i need to focus on next text input on iOS Safari which only allows such thing by a user action (e.g user click).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try it in the onchange handler:

```js
function checkAlert(evt) {
  if (evt.target.value === "Say Hello") {
    alert('Hello');
  }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="checkAlert(event)">
  <option>Test</option>
  <option>Say Hello</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using Ids to add event listener to separate your code from html so I add an Id to your select tag with "*my-select*" for example and select this tag by its Id and add **onchange** event listener. This is the code:

```
<select id="my-select">
    <option value="1">Say Hello</option>
</select>
<script>
document.getElementById("my-select").addEventListener("change", printMsg);
function printMsg() {
    alert("Hello");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use onchange event on the select element itself.

```
<select onchange="alert('hello')">
    <option value="0">Say Hello</option>
    <option value="1">Some other option</option>
</select>
```

hope that helps,