# Show radio buttons on specific selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make a selection see my choice, and based on that choice, show or hide a radio button selection.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("elevator");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-sm-2">
  <label for="selectfloor">Select Floor</label>
  <select class="form-control" onchange="myFunction()">
      <option>Stue (Ground Floor)</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
      <option>11</option>
      <option>12</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" id="elevator">
  Is there an elevator?
  <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio">No</label>
  </div>
            </div>
```

I tried onSelect but it doesnt do anything, as far as i understand once the option with myFuction is selected the radio buttons should appear. I also placed hidden on the div of the radio buttons to hide them so they could appear after i select a certain option. Any solution would help.

Comment: For starters, `getElementsById` should be `getElementById`.

Comment: Thanks! fixed that :) still not sure where im stuck :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```js
function myFunction(selected) {

  var x = document.getElementById("elevator");

  if (selected.value == "Stue (Ground Floor)") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-sm-2">
  <label for="selectfloor">Select Floor</label>

  <select class="form-control" onchange="myFunction(this)">
    <option>Stue (Ground Floor)</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" id="elevator" hidden>
  Is there an elevator?
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio">No</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for me but if remove the hidden value on the elevator it just hides the elevator when i select stue (ground floor), and i want the elevator to be hidden from the start (when the form loads)

Comment: That is why you need to keep the "hidden" property for the DIV. It ensure that the  question/radio buttons about elevator is hidden when the page first loads.  Without "hidden" the elevator question will be visible on first load. Run my code snippet again.

Answer (score 0):

instead of onclick on everyoption, do onChange on the select itself.

```
function myFunction() {
  x =this;
  if (isNaN(x.value)) {

    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Comment: removed hidden from the elevator div, it works with onChange but every time i select a new option, it just switches from hidden to shown. And I would like to show elevator div only when the numbers are selected, not the Stue (ground floor)

Comment: for that, you need to change the  myFunction(). add the if condition in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the event in the *select* element instead of *option*. Also you have to change the event from *onclick* to *onchange*.

Try the following way:

```js
function myFunction(el){
  var elevator = document.getElementById('elevator');
  if(el.value == "Stue (Ground Floor)")
    elevator.style.display = "none";
  else
    elevator.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-sm-2">
  <label for="selectfloor">Select Floor</label>
  <select class="form-control" onchange="myFunction(this)">
      <option>Stue (Ground Floor)</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" id="elevator" hidden>
  Is there an elevator?
  <div class="radio">
      <label><input name="rad" type="radio" id="yes">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
      <label><input name="rad" type="radio" id="no">No</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works in a way but not what I expected, I want to make it so that when the Stue option is selected the div with the id=elevator would hide from view, and when any number is selected the div would show up. hope you understood :)

Comment: When I have the attribute hidden on the element elevator it does not work, but when I remove it, it works but only when i press on a number and then press on the stue (ground floor), my plan is to hide the radio buttons onload and then show then whenever a floor is selected.

Comment: @LukasKlinga, that is what it is, since initially the suite is selected, you have to hide the radio buttons on page load.

Answer (score 0):

There is no [oncklick handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51347363/adding-onclick-event-to-html-select-option) on `option` tag so use onchange on `select` tag.
And Check if value is NaN(not a number)

```js
function myFunction(option) {
  var x = document.getElementById("elevator");
  // if option value is Not a Number
  if (isNaN(option.value)) {

    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-sm-2">
  <label for="selectfloor">Select Floor</label>
  <select class="form-control" onchange="myFunction(this)">
    <option>Stue (Ground Floor)</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" id="elevator" hidden>
  Is there an elevator?
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio">No</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Below code might help you. Using onChange you can call a function which gets the index of the selection and uses it to display the radio buttons. I have used the "display" property of css to hide/unhide the radio buttons. keep in mind that the name of the radio buttons sould be same for individual selection. In this case i am checking if there are more than one floors to  display the radio buttons.

```
 <form>
        <label for="selectfloor">Select Floor</label>
          <select id="selectfloor" onchange="myFunction()">
                            <option>Stue (Ground Floor)</option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                            <option>7</option>
                            <option>8</option>
                            <option>9</option>
                            <option>10</option>
                            <option>11</option>
                            <option>12</option>
          </select>
        </form>

        <p id="display"></p>

                <div class="col-sm-3" style="display:none" id="elevator">
                    Is there an elevator?
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input name="elevatorAvailable" type="radio">Yes</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input  name="elevatorAvailable" type="radio">No</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

        <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("selectfloor");
            var i = x.selectedIndex;
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML ="floor selected : " + x.options[i].text;
            if(i>1){
            document.getElementById('elevator').style.display = 'block';
            }else{
                document.getElementById('elevator').style.display = 'none';
                 }
          }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Few Points to remember

- Dont use onclick in `<option>` use onchange on `<select>` instead.
- if you are dealing with "hidden" attribute on element you can not alter style attribute by `display : none/block`
- `if condition` can be made robust in your code, use `<select>` value to achieve the goal

here is the working example with "hidden" attribute 
https://jsfiddle.net/gmall/epbc63w8/1/

Hope that helps!!!