# Why my JS code is not working if I called my JS function inside PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating a dynamic form in PHP. The below code is a part of the PHP file. When the user selects the radio option an alert message has to appear. So I called the JS function inside it and this function will be activated when the user clicks the radio option. Then I added a script tag after the ending PHP to include my JS code. But the problem is when I click the option radio an alert message is not appearing. (i.e. JS code is not working)

```
<?php...................
<select name='choose' class='choose'>
<option value='radio' onclick='radio()'>RADIO</option>
<option value='checkbox'>CHECK BOX</option>
<option value='email'>EMAIL</option>
<option value='file'>FILE</option>
<option value='tel'>TELEPHONE</option>
?>
 <script>
 function radio(){
        alert("hi");
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: option tag does not support `onClick()` event. You can use `onChange()` with the select tag, then check the selected value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding onclick event to html select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51347363/adding-onclick-event-to-html-select-option)

Comment: replace instant `onClick` to `onChange` and also `option` to `select` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
 echo "<select name='choose' id='choose' class='choose' onclick='selectfun()'> 
         <option value='radio' onclick='radio()'>RADIO</option>
         <option value='checkbox'>CHECK BOX</option>
         <option value='email'>EMAIL</option>
         <option value='file'>FILE</option>
         <option value='tel'>TELEPHONE</option></select>";
?>


 <script>
  function selectfun() {
  // initializing the select tag to the variable selectBox
  var selectBox = document.getElementById("choose");
  // onclick reading the option value by select tag index
  var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
   // checking the selected value is `radio` or not
   if(selectedValue == 'radio'){
   // if selected value is radio then alert the selected value
    alert(selectedValue);
   }
  }
  </script>
```

you can use `echo` of PHP to print the HTML code, please check my above code that may give you some idea how to do it.
and it's easy to bind `onclick` event to the select tag instead of an option, [reference here](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-280-lack-of-events-for-options.html)

here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/designerPrasanna/2m0wq5sg/)

Comment: Yes, It's working when you add onclick to select tag. but in my case, I added onclick event to the radio option mine wasn't working?Can you please specify it? then I could not understand this code line(    var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value; ) can you please explain? Thank you so much.

Comment: hi @Pikachu please check the updated answer, I had added comments and reference why `onclick` does not work for the option tag. if this is worked for you please accept the answer

Comment: Thank you @codeBug it's working now but What if I have multiple select tags then How it's going to work?

Comment: if you have multiple select tags you can't use `id` we have to go for another method,

Comment: Can you please specify?

Comment: sure why not, rise another question related to that, I will specify, also don't forget to make it as accept

Comment: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64695694/how-can-i-add-alert-button-to-the-radio-option-if-i-have-multiple-select-tags-wi) @CodeBug